# Using suffixes for dictionary searching

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

P/S: Duplicates questions raised so far are concerning on prefixes (thanks for that anyway)
This question is on suffixes.

With dictionary

```
dic={"abcd":2, "bbcd":2, "abgg":2}
```

Is it possible to search the dictionary using suffix of the string, i.e., if given "bcd", it will return me two entries

```
{"abcd":2, "bbcd":2}
```

One possible way:

```
dic1={}
for k, v in dic.items():
    if(k.endswith("bcd")):
        dic1[k]=v
```

Is it possible to do it more efficiently?

Comment: @simonzack This is regarding suffix, a completely different question

Comment: If you understand tries, you understand how to store suffixes. Just store the suffixes instead of the prefixes.

Comment: @simonzack I know trie, is there a trie implementation (a library) that supports suffixes?

Comment: You don't need to find one. Just reverse the string before and after putting it in the trie.

Comment: @simonzack that is an additional operations for reversing...

Comment: Only a constant factor difference. Python isn't that performant anyway.

Comment: it's an O(n) different, n is the length of the words...I hope to get more efficient one, otherwise I would not ask this question :) @simonzack

Comment: Exactly, and constructing the trie requires \Omega(n), hence the constant factor. But anyway, if performance is such a big deal good luck on your quest.

Answer (score 0):

for a small problems set you can do it with a simple list comprehension:

```
suffixed = [v for k, v in dic.items() if k.endswith("bcd")]
```

however that means doing a substring check on every item in the dictionary every time you query. If that's slow on big data sets you can make a second dictionary of the original keys as an acceleration. You'd have to do a one time pre-pass:

```
suffixes = dict ( [ (k[-3:], []) for k in dic1] ) 
for k in dic1:
    suffixes[k[-3:]].append(dic1[k])
```

That would give you all the results for each suffix. You could store the keys instead of the values the same way and then chain to a lookup.

In any event, the hashed lookups for dictionary keys are very cheap, so it's best to cache your data in a dictionary with the keys you want (ie, suffixes) rather than looping over every key doing strings.